# In redmine plugin get issues update note

Tags: redmine, redmine-plugins

i want to develop a redmine plugin about manage project. 
But I can not find out that how to get issues update notes.
is there any API to get this message?

Answer (score 0):

try to examine this plugin - it will add webhook calls - if it's what you're looking for :)

Regards
Maxim

Comment: can i get some ruby api?

Comment: @Maxim Krušina, have you forgotten link?

Answer (score 0):

You can find all notes in the Journals table.

Each issue has many journals, each journal may have a note and many journal_details.

You generally don't need to use the Redmine Rest API when developing plugins.

Comment: can i get some ruby api to get this journals?